# Operating System: Is it possible to convert DOS to Window?

Tags: operating-systems

I have a DOS machine that I want to change to  Windows Operating System.

Is this possible? If yes, can anyone explain the procedure to me?

Comment: Is this a 'new' system that comes with freedos? You should just be able to pop in a disk of an appropriate version of windows, boot from it by selecting it in bios, and install windows as you would any machine.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the manufacturer provides hardware drivers for the version of Windows you want to install (check the site and search for your laptop model), you should have no problems booting from the DVD (or USB) and installing the OS.

I recommend you download all the drivers on another PC and keep them handy on a USB stick/flash drive so you can install them easily first thing after Windows is up and running.

Comment: P.S. I didn't bother addressing the last bit of your question because there are probably thousands of sites with detailed tutorials teaching you how to install Windows. If you're not confident get someone halfway knowledgeable about computers to help you.